# Windows Server 2008 Keyb/Mouse non-responsive at Login Screen?

Tags: windows, login, keyboard, mouse

I have a new install of Windows Server 2008 on a RAID machine under 1 year old (machine previously had Ubuntu on it).  Windows server installed fine, created admin account etc.  After the install when rebooting I'm getting an odd problem.

The keyboard and mouse are non-responsive on the login screen (CTRL+ALT+DELETE to login).

The keyboard and mouse both 'light up', the keyboard works at a BIOS level.  Both devices work in other machines too.  Its only once Windows loads to they become non-responsive.

I have the same problem when using different keyboard/mouse combinations on this machine.  fine at BIOS level, fail at Windows login screen.

Tried booting in safe mode - same problem.  tried powering down, leaving for a bit, rebooting again - same problem.

Have tried various keyboards and mice in various USB ports - same problem.

Has anyone else come across this? It has me completely stumped.

Comment: Can you remote desktop into this box? Access it in any way over the network? I.e. are you sure it isn't actually hanging?

Comment: Hey tomfanning, thanks for the response.  I've not tried remoting in, as I've not yet hooked it up for this / the network (that was my next step, heh).  I suppose it could be hanging, but I'm relatively certain its not this - just doesn't look like it.  Any other ideas? :)

Comment: Honestly, try it, just to make sure. Have you got a USB mouse you can plug in? Remember it will take up to about a minute to initialise the first time you plug it into a given USB port.

Comment: Yep, tried multiple USB mice, no dice.  I'll see if i can remote. thx!

Comment: I'm becoming more and more certain that box has hung!

Comment: Maybe your USB controller is too new or too uncommon and Win2k8 does not have drivers for it yet. I would try accessing remotely as others suggested and check for unsupported hardware in "device manager".

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the server remotely (RDP) and validate that it has drivers for your particular USB controller or hub.  From what you said it sounds like USB isn't working at all.  If PS/2 is available you should try that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just connect a PS2 mouse and keyboard to access console. Check later if USB drivers are correctly installed on Windows Device Manager page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I recovered it with the USB Recover tool in Kaspersky Rescue Disk.

https://support.kaspersky.com/krd18/tools/14221